# How can I put the clock into the background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use visual studio to code my program. And I create a clock in the page, however I wanna put the clock into the page. My question is how to put the clock into the page.  Which tag I have to add something. Please everyone help me, thanks.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>transform</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    canvas {
      background-color: cornsilk;
      border: 1px solid cadetblue;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .main-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1080px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .img-background {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    h1 {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 15%;
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 8vw;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
    }
    
    #clock {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 9vw;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      margin-top: 25%;
    }
    
    .button {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: #f4511e;
      border: none;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 28px;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 200px;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    
    .button span {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .button span:after {
      content: '\00bb';
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: -20px;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .button:hover span {
      padding-right: 25px;
    }
    
    .button:hover span:after {
      opacity: 1;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="realtimeClock()" onload="init()">
  <div class="main-container" class="canvas">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <div id="clock"></div>third_semester\computer\background.jpg">
  </div>
  <script>
    var canvas;
    var g;
    var radius;

    //realtimeClock() is show what time is the clock is.
    function realtimeClock() {
      var rtClock = new Date();

      var hours = rtClock.getHours();
      var minutes = rtClock.getMinutes();
      var seconds = rtClock.getSeconds();
      var amPm = (hours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
      hours = (hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours;

      hours = ("0" + hours).slice(-2);
      minutes = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2);
      seconds = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);

      document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML =
        hours + "  :  " + minutes + "  :  " + seconds + " " + amPm;

      var t = setTimeout(realtimeClock, 500);
    }

    //init() is clock

    function init() {
      canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      g = canvas.getContext('2d');
      radius = canvas.height / 2 * 0.9;
      setInterval(drawClock, 1000);
    }

    function drawClock() {
      g.save();
      g.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      g.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
      drawFace();
      drawText();
      drawTime();
      g.restore();
    }

    function drawFace() {
      g.beginPath(); // outer cicle
      g.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      g.fillStyle = 'rgb(30,30,120,0.5)';
      g.fill();

      grad = g.createRadialGradient(0, 0, radius * 0.90, 0, 0, radius * 1.1);
      grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
      grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgb(30,30,70,0.5)');
      grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
      g.strokeStyle = grad;
      g.lineWidth = radius * 0.1;
      g.stroke();

      g.beginPath(); //inner circle
      g.arc(0, 0, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      g.fillStyle = '#fff';
      g.fill();
    }

    function drawText() {
      g.font = 24 + "px arial";
      g.textBaseline = "middle";
      g.textAlign = "center";
      for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        g.save();
        g.rotate(Math.PI / 6 * i)
        g.translate(0, -radius * 0.85)
        g.rotate(-Math.PI / 6 * i)
        g.fillText('' + i, 0, 0);
        g.restore();
      }
    }

    function drawTime() {
      var date = new Date();

      seconds = date.getSeconds() * 6;
      minites = (date.getMinutes() + date.getSeconds() / 60) * 6;
      hours = (date.getHours() + (date.getMinutes() + date.getSeconds() / 60) / 60) % 12 * 30

      drawHand(seconds, radius * 0.8, 3);
      drawHand(minites, radius * 0.65, 7);
      drawHand(hours, radius * 0.5, 10);
    }

    function drawHand(angle, length, width) {
      g.save();
      g.beginPath();
      g.lineCap = 'round';
      g.lineWidth = width;
      g.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
      g.moveTo(0, 0);
      g.lineTo(0, -length);
      g.stroke();
      g.restore();
    }
    init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you're trying to do is to put the clock in the background of the page.
Since the clock is already drawn onto the `canvas` tag, which has an `id` of the same name, it would be enough to modify the `position` and `z-index` of the canvas in this way:

```
canvas {
    position: absolute; /* set position to absolute */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: cornsilk;
    border: 1px solid cadetblue;
    z-index: -1; /* set z-index to -1 to send it to the background */
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>transform</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    canvas {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: cornsilk;
      border: 1px solid cadetblue;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .main-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1080px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .img-background {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    h1 {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 15%;
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 8vw;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
    }
    
    #clock {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 9vw;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      margin-top: 25%;
    }
    
    .button {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: #f4511e;
      border: none;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 28px;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 200px;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    
    .button span {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .button span:after {
      content: '\00bb';
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: -20px;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .button:hover span {
      padding-right: 25px;
    }
    
    .button:hover span:after {
      opacity: 1;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="realtimeClock()" onload="init()">
  <div class="main-container" class="canvas">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <div id="clock"></div>third_semester\computer\background.jpg">
  </div>
  <script>
    var canvas;
    var g;
    var radius;

    //realtimeClock() is show what time is the clock is.
    function realtimeClock() {
      var rtClock = new Date();

      var hours = rtClock.getHours();
      var minutes = rtClock.getMinutes();
      var seconds = rtClock.getSeconds();
      var amPm = (hours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
      hours = (hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours;

      hours = ("0" + hours).slice(-2);
      minutes = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2);
      seconds = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);

      document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML =
        hours + "  :  " + minutes + "  :  " + seconds + " " + amPm;

      var t = setTimeout(realtimeClock, 500);
    }

    //init() is clock

    function init() {
      canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      g = canvas.getContext('2d');
      radius = canvas.height / 2 * 0.9;
      setInterval(drawClock, 1000);
    }

    function drawClock() {
      g.save();
      g.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      g.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
      drawFace();
      drawText();
      drawTime();
      g.restore();
    }

    function drawFace() {
      g.beginPath(); // outer cicle
      g.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      g.fillStyle = 'rgb(30,30,120,0.5)';
      g.fill();

      grad = g.createRadialGradient(0, 0, radius * 0.90, 0, 0, radius * 1.1);
      grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
      grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgb(30,30,70,0.5)');
      grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
      g.strokeStyle = grad;
      g.lineWidth = radius * 0.1;
      g.stroke();

      g.beginPath(); //inner circle
      g.arc(0, 0, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      g.fillStyle = '#fff';
      g.fill();
    }

    function drawText() {
      g.font = 24 + "px arial";
      g.textBaseline = "middle";
      g.textAlign = "center";
      for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        g.save();
        g.rotate(Math.PI / 6 * i)
        g.translate(0, -radius * 0.85)
        g.rotate(-Math.PI / 6 * i)
        g.fillText('' + i, 0, 0);
        g.restore();
      }
    }

    function drawTime() {
      var date = new Date();

      seconds = date.getSeconds() * 6;
      minites = (date.getMinutes() + date.getSeconds() / 60) * 6;
      hours = (date.getHours() + (date.getMinutes() + date.getSeconds() / 60) / 60) % 12 * 30

      drawHand(seconds, radius * 0.8, 3);
      drawHand(minites, radius * 0.65, 7);
      drawHand(hours, radius * 0.5, 10);
    }

    function drawHand(angle, length, width) {
      g.save();
      g.beginPath();
      g.lineCap = 'round';
      g.lineWidth = width;
      g.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
      g.moveTo(0, 0);
      g.lineTo(0, -length);
      g.stroke();
      g.restore();
    }
    init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```